# Selenium WebDriver ожидание перед click()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Сейчас мои тесты выглядят примерно так:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().PlusInsideSection));
    webSite.mainPage().PlusInsideSection.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().ElementParagraph));
    webSite.mainPage().ElementParagraph.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().Plus));
    webSite.mainPage().Plus.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().AddPrebuilt));
    webSite.mainPage().AddPrebuilt.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().AddBanner));
    webSite.mainPage().AddBanner.click();
```

То есть ожидание приходится писать перед каждым действием. Есть ли способ как-то обернуть или переопределить метод `click()`, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз вручную прописывать ожидания? Если есть, то как его реализовать?

Comment: ЯП держим в секрете.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Ну, во-первых, метод `until` и так возвращает ожидаемый элемент, можно сразу по нему и кликать:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webSite.mainPage().PlusInsideSection)).click();
```

Во-вторых, ожидания лучше добавить внутрь атрибутов вашего объекта `webSite.mainPage()`, а не переопределять метод `click()`. Т.е., на сколько понял, ваш объект `webSite.mainPage().PlusInsideSection` возвращает что-то типа `driver.find_element(...)`, так вот, замените это на `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By(...)))`